How to delete storage volumes along with EKS cluster?
I have this terraform script which spins up my EKS cluster. My problem is that when I run a terraform destroy to take down the cluster, the storage volumes are not automatically deleted, I have to go into the AWS console and delete them manually. Is there a way to automate this inside of my script?
eks.tf
# Copyright (c) HashiCorp, Inc.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MPL-2.0

provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  profile = var.profile
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      Name          = "Example Eks cluster"
      
    }
  }
}

# Filter out local zones, which are not currently supported 
# with managed node groups
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  filter {
    name   = "opt-in-status"
    values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
  }
}

locals {
  cluster_name              = "test-eks-cluster"
  cluster_enabled_log_types = []
}



module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.15.3"

  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.27"

  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true
  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true

  vpc_id     = "id"
  subnet_ids = ["subnet-0354234234329e", "subnet-2343243"]

  cluster_enabled_log_types = local.cluster_enabled_log_types

  create_cloudwatch_log_group = false

  tags = var.tags


  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    #ami_type = "ami-06d7aa002b2e3009b"
    ami_type = "AL2_x86_64"
    tags     = var.tags


  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    one = {
      name = "node-group-1"

      instance_types = ["t3.large"]

      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 3
      desired_size = 2
      tags         = var.tags
    }
  }
  # access_entries = {

  #}
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy"
}

module "irsa-ebs-csi" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-assumable-role-with-oidc"
  version = "4.7.0"

  create_role                   = true
  role_name                     = "AmazonEKSTFEBSCSIRole-${module.eks.cluster_name}"
  provider_url                  = module.eks.oidc_provider
  role_policy_arns              = [data.aws_iam_policy.ebs_csi_policy.arn]
  oidc_fully_qualified_subjects = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"]
  tags                          = var.tags
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs-csi" {
  cluster_name             = module.eks.cluster_name
  addon_name               = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  addon_version            = "v1.30.0-eksbuild.1"
  service_account_role_arn = module.irsa-ebs-csi.iam_role_arn
  configuration_values = jsonencode({
    controller = {
      extraVolumeTags = {
        Name          = "Example Eks cluster"
     
      }
    }
  })
}


I expected the terraform destroy command to remove these volumes as a part of the destroy process, but they are defaulted to retain. Manually deleting the volumes works but this needs to be automated.

you meant the volume of ec2 instances ?

Yes, for the ec2 instances

In your case, you should define delete_on_termination = true for block_device_mappings  of ec2 instance, looks like this :
eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    ami_type              = "AL2_x86_64"
    instance_types        = [ "t3.large" ]

    block_device_mappings = {
      xvda = {
        device_name = "/dev/xvda"
        ebs         = {
          volume_size           = 20
          ..................        
          delete_on_termination = true
        }
      }
    }
  }

The xvda device name refers to the primary root volume of an Amazon EC2 instance. It stands for "Xen Virtual Device Adapter" and is the standard device name used for the root volume of EC2 instances.
In the context of EKS (Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service) managed node groups, the root volume is the primary storage volume that the EC2 instance uses to boot the operating system and run the Kubernetes node.
Regarding the block_device_mappings configuration, you can indeed add a block like this to ensure the root volume is deleted when the EC2 instance is terminated.
Refer: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest/submodules/eks-managed-node-group#input_block_device_mappings

Could you explain what the xvda is for? is it sufficient to just add a block_device_mappings block and simply set delete_on_termination = true?

I added into the answer
